# how move buffer vim the position 4 to 2

Tags: optimization, vim, text, ide, buffer

I want know how to move a buffer in the position 4 to position 2.

How can do it?

Buffer:

[image: buffer]

Buffer list:

[image: buffer list]

Comment: I think this [post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/466/7339) would come in handy once its title is "Renumbering buffer list"

Answer (score 3):

1. Once a buffer is added to the buffer list its index can not be changed.
2. Once an index has been used it is unusable for other buffers.
3. It is impossible to specify the index at which you want to add a buffer to the buffer list.
4. It is impossible to swap two buffers.
5. It is impossible to nudge the buffers in the buffer list.

So no, you can not.

Comment: thanks, i will try send a recommendation to github vim

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the arglist instead of bufflist, the arglist is a subset of bufflist. There is a [vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/populating-the-arglist/) about it.

Basically you can creat a file with the correct order of your files and do:

```
vim `cat list-of-files`
```

Comment: Related [vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episodes: [Meet the arglist](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-arglist/), [Populating the arglist](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/populating-the-arglist/), [Using :argdo to change multiple files](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-argdo-to-change-multiple-files/)